How to deal with exposure status change and outcome contribution in different exposure status?
I want to estimate the risk of cardiovascular events in patients with diabetes (exposed group) compared to patients without diabetes (unexposed group). How do we deal (in the analysis) with patients who are free of diabetes (unexposed group) and have a cardiovascular event, and after that develop diabetes (that is, they changed from unexposed to exposed but had the event of interest when unexposed)?
Is the best strategy to use a time-varying analysis or maybe create matched sets of patients with and without the exposure of interest at the same calendar time?
